# How to access view sublayers in swift

Tags: ios, swift, calayer

I would like to access view sublayers in swift 4.1 by writting :

```
for layer : CALayer in myView.layer.sublayers {
         // Code
}
```

but get the error :

> Type '[CALayer]?' does not conform to protocol 'Sequence'

Does that mean that `CALayer` is unreachable by for loop ?

Comment: I got an error because it was a optional nothing with sequence.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

The `sublayers` property is an *optional* array (and by default `nil`).
You have to unwrap it first, e.g. with optional binding:

```
if let sublayers = myView.layer.sublayers {
    for layer in sublayers {
        // ...
    }
}
```

Alternatively with optional chaining and `forEach`:

```
myView.layer.sublayers?.forEach { layer in
    // ...
}
```