# Animate layer below the button when the button is pressed

Tags: ios, swift

I have a layer and a button with clear background on top of it. The button is custom class that would only send an action when it's inside the layer. What I want to achieve is to animate the layer if the button is pressed.

How do I identify the layer below the button in the view hierarchy and let it animate in the buttonClicked method.

[image]

EDIT :

The example code for the layer :

```
            let endAngle = startAngle + 2 * .pi * (outerSegments[i].value / valueCount)
            let shape = CAShapeLayer()
            let path: UIBezierPath = UIBezierPath()
            path.addArc(withCenter: viewCenter, radius: outerRadius, startAngle: startAngle, endAngle: endAngle, clockwise: true)
            path.addArc(withCenter: viewCenter, radius: innerRadius, startAngle: endAngle, endAngle: startAngle, clockwise: false)
            path.close()
            shape.path = path.cgPath
            
            outerSegments[i].path = path
            
            shape.fillColor = outerSegments[i].color.cgColor
            shape.strokeColor = UIColor.black.cgColor
            shape.borderWidth = 1.0
            shape.borderColor = UIColor.black.cgColor
            self.layer.addSublayer(shape)
            ...
            // We have another textlayer on top of the layer 
            let textLayer = CATextLayer()
             ...
            let b = MyButton(type: .custom)
            b.path = path
            b.backgroundColor = UIColor.clear
            let frameRect = shape.bounds
            b.frame = frameRect
```

Comment: When you say "layer", do you mean a uiview? Don't you have a reference to that layer? If not, how is it created?

Comment: @rs7 By layer, I mean its a CALayer that is created (not of a circular shape this is just an example). There are multiple layers and buttons added on top of the view. Hope this clarifies what you are trying to ask

Comment: what you have tried so far ?

Comment: can you tell little bit how make this layer ? give an code example for make ur clear ..

Comment: @dper you can achieve this many way Like you can use Observer pattern using RxSwift or notification Center or you can  achieve it using callback ..how show your layer code how you make layer and and how you attached it to your view behind the button ..Thank you .

Comment: @dper Thank you for clarifying. Can you share the code where you created the layer?

Comment: @EkramulHoque I have added the code for the shape and button. Hope this helps on clarifying.

Comment: @rs7 I have added the code, Hope this helps

Comment: Declare the shape variable at the top of your class and that way you can access it when needed.

Comment: @dper you want any animation when you click button . so you can declear your button top of the class and when user click button just start your animation ..i dont know what animation you want to play ..

Comment: @rs7 the shape is dynamically created in the view, there are multiple shapes as well, we are keeping the track of the shapes using an ID. Not sure what you meant by declare it at top of the class.

Comment: @EkramulHoque The button background is already clear, my issue is to identify the layer below the button so that I can do the animation. The problem is to identify the layer underneath

Comment: We are missing quite a bit of information. What is self? Where is the code you posted located? Where are you trying to access the layer from?

Comment: This might help you: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51554457/how-to-access-view-sublayers-in-swift